# how to deal with c void in Julia v0.4

Tags: c, julia

The exposed API from c is:

```
bam_hdr_t *bam_hdr_init(void);
```

how do I write its wrapper in Julia?

`ccall((:bam_hdr_init,"lib.so"), Ptr{bam_hdr_t})` works in Julia v0.5, but not in v0.4.

Comment: *void* just means *no-parameters* :S

Comment: ^_^小郭，你好~~·············

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ccall((:bam_hdr_init,"lib.so"), Ptr{bam_hdr_t},())` works for both versions of Julia